# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f06005b on Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem when i'm trying use the app on a tablet. 
The error is: 
[image]

The android version of the tablet is 5.0.2 API 21 
and the grandle settings are:

`compileSdkVersion 26, 
 minSdkVersion 19, 
 targetSdkVersion 26`

If i run the app on my cellphone Android version is 7.0 API 24 has no problem.

The App start on tablet but when I try to get in to a specific activity the app crashes. 
Please help and thank you.

Comment: post your code in `Method.java` around the line 372 (shown in blue in the error)

Comment: that shown in blue because i click there before the sreenshot, but normally all the links shown in grey

Comment: you are using butterknife?

Comment: no, i did not use butterknife

Comment: check your `res` folder .... maybe there is separated folder for different screen sizes

Comment: problem solved, on res folder i had drawable and drawable-24, i cut and paste the icon on drawable-24 and paste on drawable folder, that sove my problem, thanks.

Comment: Post this as an answer and mark it as accepted so this question can be marked as answered. Thank you.